# How to read discussions on Twitter in a tree view?

Tags: browser-addons, twitter, tree-view

Twitter’s desktop website uses “View other replies” links to open sub-branches of a discussion. This makes it very hard (for me) to follow a discussion, because I have to constantly move between the main discussion and its sub-branches (not to mention, that the sub-branches themselves can have other sub-branches).

A tree view would be a better UI representation of a discussion (think Reddit). Is there a tool, plugin, library, etc. that would replace Twitter’s current discussions UI with a proper tree view (at least, when viewing a specific discussion)?